# Cannot perform "npm install repo" from bitbucket using a ssh key on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, bitbucket, npm-install

I performed a npm install from a private repository from bitbucket using a ssh key.

I have the following bitbucket guide and added the public key in the bitbucket setting but it still throws the following error:

```
(node:9972) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
npm ERR! git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  resetting remote C:\Users\Tran Nam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-bitbucket-org-auvene-authenticate-api-git-ebd869eb because of error: { Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
npm WARN addRemoteGit   killed: false,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   signal: null,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url' }
npm ERR! git -c core.longpaths=true clone --template=C:\Users\Tran Nam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@bitbucket.org/auvene/authenticate-api.git C:\Users\Tran Nam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-bitbucket-org-auvene-authenticate-api-git-ebd869eb
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Tran Nam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@bitbucket.org/auvene/authenticate-api.git C:\Users\Tran Nam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-bitbucket-org-auvene-authenticate-api-git-ebd869eb: Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\Tran Nam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-bitbucket-org-auvene-authenticate-api-git-ebd869eb'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Tran Nam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@bitbucket.org/auvene/authenticate-api.git C:\Users\Tran Nam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-bitbucket-org-auvene-authenticate-api-git-ebd869eb: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Tran Nam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@bitbucket.org/auvene/authenticate-api.git C:\Users\Tran Nam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-bitbucket-org-auvene-authenticate-api-git-ebd869eb: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Tran Nam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@bitbucket.org/auvene/authenticate-api.git C:\Users\Tran Nam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-bitbucket-org-auvene-authenticate-api-git-ebd869eb:
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Tran Nam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@bitbucket.org/auvene/authenticate-api.git C:\Users\Tran Nam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-bitbucket-org-auvene-authenticate-api-git-ebd869eb: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Tran Nam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@bitbucket.org/auvene/authenticate-api.git C:\Users\Tran Nam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-bitbucket-org-auvene-authenticate-api-git-ebd869eb: and the repository exists.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Tran Nam\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/auvene/authenticate-api"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.5
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true clone --template=C:\Users\Tran Nam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@bitbucket.org/auvene/authenticate-api.git C:\Users\Tran Nam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-bitbucket-org-auvene-authenticate-api-git-ebd869eb
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\Tran Nam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-bitbucket-org-auvene-authenticate-api-git-ebd869eb'...
npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     e:\CONG VIEC\Auvene\tmt-app\npm-debug.log
```

On Windows 10.